An example a right Noetherian domain which is left uniform but not right uniform
Recall that a module $M_R$ ($R$ is a ring with unity) is called uniform if the intersection of any two nonzero submodules is nonzero. We say that $M_R$ is an SIP-module if the intersection of any two summands is also a summand.
I have two questions:

Consider the ring $R:=K[x; \sigma]$ ($K$ is a field, and $\sigma:K \to K$ is a ring monomorphism which is not surjective) of twisted polynomial rings with coefficients on the left (or left polynomials), where addition is polynomial addition, and $xk=\sigma(k)x$ for every $k\in K$. Is every right ideal of $R$ an SIP-$R$-module?. It is well-known that $R$ is a domain which is not right uniform (because for $c \in K \setminus \sigma(K)$ we have $xR \cap cxR=0$). Observe that if $A=fR$ is a nonzero cyclic submodule of $R_R$, then the right $R$-module epimorphism $R \to fR$ given by $r \mapsto fr$ is an $R$-module isomorphism (as $R$ is a domain). Hence, every nonzero cyclic submodule of $R_R$ isomorphic to $R_R$. Since $R_R$ is an SIP module (because it is a domain and hence indecomposable), then every nonzero cyclic submodule of $R_R$ is also SIP. Are the non-cyclic submodules of $R_R$ also SIP?
Is there an example of a right noetherian domain which is left uniform but not right uniform? (I appreciate if the details are all included or the references are provided)


It is well-known that a right Noetherian domain is right Ore, hence right uniform.  So the answer to 2 is negative.

This is not true. Take $R=\mathbb{F}_2[x,y]/(x,y)^2$, where $\mathbb{F}_2$ is the field of two elements. This ring is finite, hence noetherian. Take the principal ideals generated by $x+(x,y)^2$ and $y+(x,y)^2$. Indeed, the intersection of these two ideals is zero. So, $R$ is not uniform.

That is not a domain, friend.  See for example Corollary 10.23, p 304 in Lam's Lectures on Modules and Rings.

Oh! I'm so sorry. I didn't notice that $R$ is not a domain.
